# Adding and using plugins on Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, ionic2

Please, I need a final step-by-step to add and use plugins with Ionic.
I lost several weeks trying to use plugins on Ionic but everytime I got *plugin function* "is not defined". I really need to solve this issue, but I don't got success.

First of all I'm not trying to use native plugins that uses special hardware components like camera. I'm following the steps below:

1) I created my app using cordova

2) I added my plugin using:

> cordova plugin add mercadopago-plugin

3) I've inserted this following scripts on my index.html:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

4) I created a button calling my plugin on my template.html

```
<button ng-click="startCheckout()"> OK </button>
```

5) I called my plugin on app.js

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {    
        $scope.carrinho = allcarrinho;      
        var publicKey = "TEST";
        $scope.startCheckout = function(){
                MercadoPago.startCheckout(publicKey, prefId, null, false, success, failure);
        }               
})
```

6) I've emulated my app on the browser typing on my admin prompt command:

```
ionic serve
```

But when the plugin is called I got this error:

> ReferenceError: MercadoPago is not defined

I following everything on documentation:

> Plugin's documentation: http://mercadopago.github.io/px-hybrid/

How do I to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to inject MercadoPago in your controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, MercadoPago /*<--here*/) {
```

I didn't see your full code but it has to be something like that.

or to have it not break when minifying:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'MercadoPago', function($scope, MercadoPago) { ....
```

See [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: I tried it but I got a new error: 

ionic.bundle.min.js:133 Error: [$injector:unpr] http : // errors. angularjs. org /1.3.6/$injector/unpr?p0=MercadoPagoProvider%20%3C-%20MercadoPago%20%3C-%20MyCtrl
    at Error (native)

Comment: Nothing about injection is mentioned on plugin documentation: http://mercadopago.github.io/px-hybrid/

Comment: That's weird. I checked your link and it is in spanish, but after translating it is still confusing. Maybe you shouldnt inject it but call it with window.MercadoPago.startCheckout() (or document). I dont know. Did you check if the library is loaded?

Comment: My developement's folder is "\app\www"  but here I can't see my libraries here, I only can see on "\app\platforms\browser\platform_www\plugins", "\app\platforms\ios\platform_www\plugins" and "\app\platforms\android\platform_www\plugins".

Answer (score 1):

Most Cordova plugins do not work in the browser. You should try on an emulator or simulator.

Either that, or you need to wait for `document.ready` or `ionicPlatform.ready` for the plugin to initialize before trying to use it

Answer (score 1):

This plugin makes native calls when you use ˝MercadoPago". It won't work in your browser, you should run it on an Android Emulator or Phone.

Try:

```
ionic emulate android -l -c
```

And it should work.